# JQuery getJSON() parsing yields "undefined" values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using JQuery's getJSON() to request JSON from my web server.  Then, I want to parse the response.  The format of the JSON response is as follows:

```
{
    "responseStatus": "200",
    "responseData": {
        "resultText": "Hello"
    },
    "originalText": "hi"
}
```

And my JQuery code:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (json) {
     $.each(json, function (i, result) {
         alert(result.resultText);
     });
});
```

The problem I am facing is that I receive three alert windows in a row: "Undefined", "Hello", and "Undefined".  I am only looking to get and show the single value for resultText.  Why am I also receiving the "Undefined"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do:

```
$.getJSON(url,function(json){

   alert(json.responseData.resultText);       

});
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! I'm new to JQuery, so I'm still trying to learn all of the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

`responseData` is just a plain object why are you using `$.each` loop just try

```
$.getJSON(url,function(json){
    alert(json.responseData.resultText);       
});
```

You are getting three alerts because you are looping through whole json object which has 3 properties

```
$.getJSON(url, function (json) {
     $.each(json, function (i, result) {
         //In this loop result will point to each of the properties
         //of json object and only responseData has resultText property 
         //so you will get proper alert other wise for other properties
         //it is undefined. 
         alert(result.resultText);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When you iterate through the json object, you will first have the object "responseStatus".  If you try to do responseStatus.resultText it is undefined as responseStatus does not have that property.  The same goes for "originalText"

In order to see the single result just use:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (json) {
    alert(json.responseData.resultText);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one (you can do it directly)

```
$.getJSON(url,function(json){
         alert(json.responseData.resultText);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're iterating the entire response...meaning you're hitting

1. `responseStatus`
2. `responseData`
3. `originalText`

However, **only** your `responseData` property has a `resultText` property.